# Help solving separation of variables problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the PDE separation of variables problem for the PDE

$$\dfrac{-F''(x) + 2F'(x)}{F(x)} = \lambda$$

for the cases where $\lambda$ is negative, positive, and equal to 0.

I am stuck for the case where $\lambda = -\mu^2 < 0$:

$$-F''(x) + 2F'(x) - \lambda F(x) = 0$$

I was unable to solve this DE, because I couldn't solve the characteristic polynomial $-m^2 + 2M - \lambda = 0$. Please help!

Comment: You can use an ansatz like $F(x) = C\cdot e^{\alpha x}$ to solve this differential equation.

Comment: @Wyuw : What do you mean with "separation of variables" ? I cannot see any separation of variables into what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda=-\mu^2$ the characteristic equation is
$$
-m^2+2\,m+\mu^2=0,
$$
whose solution is
$$
m=1\pm\sqrt{\mu^2+1}.
$$

Comment: Can you please show how you got $m=1\pm\sqrt{\mu^2+1}$? That is my confusion. I tried using the quadratic equation: $-m^2+2\,m+\mu^2 = -(m^2 - 2m - \mu^2) = 0$, so $m = \dfrac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4(1)(\mu^2)}}{2(1)}$

Comment: It is just the quadratic formula.$$m=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{2^2+4\,\mu^2}}{2}.$$